# Python if...elif...else statement something wrong?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm making a small tool that scrape content from a website. Everything work fine except the condition statement, it won't go to the *elif* statement, can someone tell me what wrong?

```
res = opener.open(req)
validate = res.read()
if bool(re.search(r'content-wraper', validate, re.DOTALL).group(0)) == True:
    print 'validated successful, start writing content'
    f = open('save.txt', 'a')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
elif bool(re.search(r'from this ip', validate, re.DOTALL).group(0)) == True:
    print 'Warning, IP block detected'
    break;
else:
    pass;
```

If i remove the *if* statement and change the *elif* to *if*, it work but this doesn't!

*//edit*
I've got everything sorted now by remove the group in the regex search. Thank you guys!

Comment: Should `content-wraper` be `content-wrapper`? Also you should not use `;` on single statement lines.

Comment: If you've got the question answered, feel encouraged to add it as an answer and accept it.  This way, we all know that you've got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the second condition is not satisfied, but when the first one is satisfied. The logic of if-elif is, that elif will be executed if all the previous conditions of the same statement are False, but its condition is True.

When you make if from elif, it makes a different statement, and it check also cases, when the first condition is True.

It's hard to help with this without knowing the desired logic, but one way to clarify the situation is to put conditions into variables before any IFs and print both conditions.

If you never see False-True, then it's not a surprise elif is not reached.

```
A = cond1
B = cond2
print A, B
if A:
   something
elif B:
   something2
```

Comment: There is a Nonetype error raised in the loop, i think it come from the if statement while it couldn't search the regex. How do i handle that error?

Comment: Use a try-except construct.`try: ... except NameOfTheError: ...`

Comment: There is no need to check the group, just use re.search(r'content-wraper', validate, re.DOTALL) for condition. Match object is None (and thus False), when no match.

Answer (score 1):

Pls be a little bit more precise here with the term "does not work". What does not work? Syntax errors? Logic errors?

Maybe we could start cleaning up your code...

also, you can remove the semicolons after `break;` and `pass;`, you don't need them in Python.

Do you run this in a `for` or `while` loop? Otherwise you won't need the `break` at all.

and the line

```
else:
   pass;
```

are just redundant and can be omitted.

I am not sure if I understand correctly but you want both executed one after the other: `if` clause and then the `elif`? That's impossible if you attempted to do such a thing. In this case, why don't you just use 2 `if`s?

Comment: Yeah, i'm running it in a while loop, that why i need a break. And the term "does not work" i mean it didn't go to the elif statement while the if won't satisfy it's condition.

Comment: ah sorry, now I get it

Comment: @DuongTruong: That is simply impossible.

Comment: I would suggest using the `pdb` debugger and go through it step by step to really make sure

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are overkill for this situation. Also the use of with will ensure that `req` is properly cleaned up.

This code is much easier to read.

```
with opener.open(req) as res;
    validate = res.read()
    if 'content-wrapper' in validate:
        print 'validated successful, start writing content' 
        with open('save.txt', 'a') as f
            f.write(content)
    elif 'from this ip' in validate:
        print 'Warning, IP block detected'
```